# Installing GD Perl module on Ubuntu 16

Tags: perl, gd

I'm trying to get the **GD.pm** Perl module installed on my server. I get this error when trying to install with `cpanm`:

```
Please install libgd 2.0.28 or higher.
```

I did some research, and people suggest trying to run `apt-get install perl-GD`, but as you can see from below it doesn't work:

```
root@mail:~# apt-get install perl-GD
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package perl-GD
```

I'm a bit stumped as to what else to try. I've already got the GD PHP module installed and working, so I would have thought they would be one and the same thing with the underlying software?

My server is *Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS*, with *PHP 7* and *Perl 5.22.1*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Eugh, and as if by magic (AGAIN!). I just found this post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324342/how-to-instal-perl-modules-gd-and-gdpolyline-in-debian

...and they suggest running:

`apt-get install libgd-perl`

Sure enough, that does the job. All working perfectly now. Maybe I should post my questions here first, instead of spending hours searching around, as it seems to be only then I find the answers ;)

Comment: Those things happen man el OH el

Comment: Thank you! Works on Ubuntu 21.04. Easily!